# Log4j - is this configuration possible?

Tags: log4j

I have 2 appenders - A, B.
By default, I want all messages go to B. If message has level >= ERROR **or** it's from com.mycomp.* logger I want it to go to A instead.

I'm trying to figure out if this configuration is possible in log4j 1.2. So far seems like it's not.

**Edit:** to clarify, here's exactly same question about Logback [logback: Two appenders, multiple loggers, different levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734025/logback-two-appenders-multiple-loggers-different-levels)

Comment: Yes. You are right, by setting same package to different error-levels/appenders overrides the other one. So I would suggest to add appenders programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using filter:

```
public class MyLogFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    public int decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        if (!loggingEvent.getLevel().isGreaterOrEqual(Level.ERROR) &&
                !loggingEvent.getLoggerName().startsWith("com.mycomp")) {
            return DENY;
        }

        return NEUTRAL;
    }
}
```

and configuration like

```
log4j.rootLogger=(INFO, A, B);
log4j.logger.com.mycomp=(INFO, A);
log4j.appenders.A.filter.a=com.mycomp.MyLogFilter;
```

Unfortunately, [you can only specify filters in log4j.xml and not in log4j.properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256893/550208)