# logback - how to specify level per appender?

Tags: android, logback

I am using logback for android.
I have two appenders, one that write to file and another appender for logcat.

How can i give different level to each appender? I would like logcat to be trace and the file to be info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an android developer but I usually use logback, you can create two different loggers each of them will point to one of your appenders, then you can assign the level of the logger.

Example :

```
<appender name="dumpA" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
...
</appender>

<appender name="dumpB" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
...
</appender>

<logger name="loggerA">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="dumpA" />
</logger>
<logger name="loggerB">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="dumpB" />
</logger>
```

Comment: what should i put in the root section?

Comment: You can leave it empty.

Comment: There is an alternative solution that uses ThresholdLoggerFilter for appenders link over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734025/logback-two-appenders-multiple-loggers-different-levels).