# Logging web application request logs to a separate file

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j

My application is on spring framework and for logging i am using LogBack and Slf4j.

I have written a filter to write request logs, currently my application as well as request log all go to a single file, as both are using log level of INFO. Is there a way i can push my application logs and requests to different files.

Any pointers and leads will be helpful.

Comment: Have seen something called Markers, will try that in the meantime someone comes back on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488558/logback-to-log-different-messages-to-two-files

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to log to different log files based on some condition and I considered using logback [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html)