# Logback - Define many Appender/Pattern for a logger / log level

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

`Spring Boot 2.3.1` web application, using a logger (default `Logback`), condiguration like in https://www.baeldung.com/logback , for example:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>...</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>...</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>...</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
  <logger name="com.me" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> 
  </logger> 
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to define two or more file appender, each with different pattern, for a logger (like "com.me")? When using in code `LOGGER.info(...)` to be able to choose witch appender/pattern to use?

Now it is configured, for `"com.me"` if `LOGGER.info(...)` is used in code, it will write to a file using appender `"FILE"`. But all my `LOGGER.info(...)` for this package (or class level) will have the same pattern, more flexibility is needed, somewhere in the code perhaps I would like to log in log level `"info"` just a simple message, with a different pattern.

Can this be done via `logback-spring.xml` configuration or programatically? For now I use:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

But the logger doesn't have any set-methods to set something.

Comment: Have you checked this? [Logback to log different messages to two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488558/logback-to-log-different-messages-to-two-files)

Comment: In that post, there are two different files to which is logged (logfile.log, analytics.log). Can file appenders share the same file for logging? I want the output to be logged to the same log file and also same console. Just the pattern shall be different.

Comment: Use a single appender but add filters according
to your need. [check this thread](http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/Multiple-FileAppenders-writing-to-single-file-no-longer-working-in-Logback-1-2-3-td16445.html)